# is it possible to return a single value from Q in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I am using the Django ORM and I would like to do something like:

```
self.queryset.annotate(cupcake_name=Q(baked_goods__frosted_goods__cupcakes__cupcake_id='xxx'))
```

but return the individual cupcake name field value somehow so I can serve it as a data attribute.

Comment: please share some more code on how you are using the queryset and the implementation of the view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the cupcake id and you want to do this in a single query you can use a `Subquery`:

```
from django.db.models import Subquery

self.queryset.annotate(
    cupcake_name=Subquery(Cupcake.objects.filter(id='xxx').values('name')),
)
```

See the Subquery docs here if you need to link the subquery to the queryset: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions

If you don't mind making two queries it's a bit more clear to use the literal `Value` expression:

```
from django.db.models import Value

cupcake_name = Cupcake.objects.get(id='xxx').name
self.queryset.annotate(
    cupcake_name=Value(cupcake_name),
)
```